# Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 (hypervisor) or Windows Server 2008 + Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm planning to build a small server for a couple small projects, which will run a couple OSs as virtual machines.

This will mostly be Windows OSs, so I decided to use the new Hyper-V functionality added in Server 2008.

What I've recently learned about is that Microsoft have their own Hypervisor os, based on the Hyper-V technology. This would be a great solution, but it seems there are a number of drawbacks. Mainly - there's hardly any information about it, and the download links have been removed from the Hyper-V website (even though they're still available at the download center). It looks like it's been buried.

Secondly - the Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 just came out, adding new functionality, like Hyper-V Dynamic Memory.

So the question would be: Is there any use in still using microsofts hypervisor, or should I use the full server 2008 R2 os + a number of VMs on it?

Should I use a different hypervisor instead? (like VmWare ESX..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't find the 2008 version is that it was superseded by the 2008 R2 version over a year ago; only the new version is available now; soon the 2008 R2 version will be unavailable as it gets displaced by the 2008 R2 SP1 version.

Plenty of people use Hyper-V Server. In "Windows" networks is the 2nd most popular hypervisor. If you don't need a desktop environment on the server, Hyper-V server is definitely preferred over Server + Hyper-V Role.

<sub>ESXi is the most popular hypervisor last time I checked. In either case there are plenty of experts around here in both.</sub>

Comment: Ah, I see.. I found the download link to the R2 version today (I swear I couldn't find it the last time) which means that the R2 SP1 version will come out soon as well.. Thanks :)